# DLL method not visible inside project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

I'm currently working on a project that has two winform applications and a class library for sharing methods/models between the two. As I'm still working on all three (one is a setup project, the other is the actual application so it's all very closely integrated), I just reference the DLL from the debug location and then rebuild all necessary projects when changes are made to the DLL to test. This worked before (yesterday) but this morning when I added a namespace, added a method to the name space, made them both public/static and then rebuilt the DLL and the winform app, the winform application failed to see the new namespace. See the code example below for the structure of the namespace and code.

```
namespace Security
{
   public class Security
    {
        public static Models.Status DoSomeWork()
        {
           // Do some work
           return new Models.Status();
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting tidbit is that applications not included in the same project can see the "Security" namespace within the DLL but the two winform applications cannot see the "Security" namespace. I restarted VS, my computer, cleared out the files in the "Debug" folder for all the applications (in case it was caching) and then tested it on a separate application (which is where I was able to see the "Security" namespace). I am at a lost and hope someone had this issue and it's something simple. I appreciate the help in advance! :)

EDIT: Modified the code to include the class since I missed that when I was first writing this.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What is the error message?

Comment: This code won't even compile, you can't have a method outside a class. Also, do you have another `Security` namespace that is conflicting?

Comment: Check which versions of the framework you're targeting for each DLL.

Comment: There is no error when building the code within the winform application, I simply cannot reference the method in question. I have another class within the DLL that I can reference (let's call it Security.Data) from within both winform applications. If I reference the DLL from a third, not included in the solution winform application, I can see the "Security.Security" class and reference the methods within it.

Comment: "Check which versions of the framework you're targeting for each DLL."

Comment: "Check which versions of the framework you're targeting for each DLL."
In the reference section in VS, there is a tiny exclamation mark if the framework version is different.

Comment: Check if the DLL you are referencing is the latest build, or simply rebuild the DLL (and check for any errors) to make sure it is.

Comment: Nope the framework versions match and VS is not showing any problems with the reference. I removed the DLL from the solution, created a new solution from it, referenced it back into the existing projects and it now works. It seems to be ONLY when the DLL is loaded into the same solution that it does not show the new classes/methods. Very strange and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have added the library reference correctly or re-add, if added then check access specifier of that method.

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: The library is added correctly or I would not be able to see any of the models/other methods within the DLL. It is public access all the way down to the particular method I need and the access modifiers match the other class I'm able to use within the same DLL. I'm just lost :(